# Improving mysql query?

Tags: mysql

My attempt was to join customer and order table and to join the lineitem and order table. I have also indexed the c_mktsegment field. My resultant query is this. Is there anything that I can do do improve it?

```
select
    o_shippriority,
    l_orderkey,
    o_orderdate,
    sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as revenue
from
    cust As c
    join ord As o on c.c_custkey = o.o_custkey
    join line As l on o.o_orderkey = l.l_orderkey
where
    c_mktsegment = ':1'
    and o_orderdate < date ':2'
    and l_shipdate > date ':2'
group by
    l_orderkey,
    o_orderdate,
    o_shippriority
order by
    revenue desc,
    o_orderdate;
```

Comment: This should probably be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with this query. For good performance, you probably should have indexes on orders.o_custkey and lineitem.l_orderkey. The index on c_mktsegment will let the DB find customer records quickly, but from there you need to be able to find order and lineitem records.

You should do an Explain to see how the db is processing the query. This depends on many factors, including the number of records in each table and distribution of keys, so I can't say what the plan is just by looking at the query. But if you run Explain and see that it is doing a full-file read of a table, you should add an index to prevent that. That's pretty much rule #1 for query optimization.